# In React 16.9, directly updating the state without setState updates UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export default class Concepts extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {
                name: 'Mayank'
            }
        }
    }

    changeUserData = () => {
        this.state.user.name = "Anshul";
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.user.name}</h1><br></br>
                <input type="button" onClick={this.changeUserData} value="Click To Change" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Even without using "setState" in React 16.9, the UI is updating.

In React 16.8, we need to call "forceUpdate", is it a problem on my side.

Comment: I just tested this, that is not what happens. Also, your onclick won't work either. Also, use setState... better yet use hooks. This is just bad code, not to hurt your feelings, but it is just bad. Don't do this. Use setState, or again, better yet, hooks.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc the `onClick` most definitely works... the handler is broken... if you change it to `setState` vs mutating the state direclty, everything works fine and looks fine. There is only 1 problem with OP's code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I directly modify a component's state, really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really)

Comment: It could look like it works because something else triggers a rerender, but it is definitely not a feature nor a bug. Immutability is not enforced within the code, but it is highly encouraged you follow the guidelines and rules around React to avoid 
problems that are surprisingly difficult to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid mutating the state directly and instead use `setState` or use hooks.

```
const [user, changeUser] = React.useState({ name: 'Roy' })
//...
changeUser(user => ({ ...user, name: 'David' }))}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change to:

```
 changeUserData = () => {

    this.setState({
        user: {name:"Anshul"}
});}
```

Comment: Read the 'question' again.

Comment: Where did  you found that the direct state update is official 
mutation state feature of 16.9?

Comment: Read the 'question' again.

Comment: It ISN'T a feature... OP is saying that in React 16.9 you are able to mutate state directly, which would be a MASSIVE bug....... That is the ENTIRE point... Mutating state directly is not a feature, it's not supposed to be allowed.

Comment: If you found a bug you can post it in related GitHub react project issues.

Comment: There is no bug.... I am not sure what OP is referring to... I created a brand new app using `create-react-app` with React 16.9 and could not reproduce this "issue".... There is no bug.. there is no issue.... nothing is wrong... THIS IS POINTLESS.

Comment: After all, you are using wrong pattern and you know about it, what is your problem?